# How does initialization of static (global) objects happen

Tags: c++, c++11, global-variables

I am trying to figure out exactly how constructors for global objects are called.  I understand that they are called before anything in a translation unit is used, and I am fine with that.  I am trying to find out how in Linux and Windows (x86 and x64) this is accomplished.

I seem to remember that Windows (x86) used a linked list for construction and destruction, but I am having trouble finding any resources on this matter.

I have found the following material on related topics, but nothing seems to cover exactly what I am looking for.

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/freik/archive/2005/03/17/398200.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9b372w95.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7kcdt6fy.aspx

And the PE file format document.

Could anyone point me in the correct direction to find this information?

Comment: Without looking at the specification, I suspect that the implementation is entirely compiler dependent, not OS dependent.

Comment: Are you asking just out of curiosity or do you have a (work / project related) problem that you think you can solve by understanding this issue?

Comment: I am going to be doing a presentation on construction/destruction of global variables.  As part I want to compare/contrast what the standard guarantees and what implementations actually do.

Comment: @Joachim Isaksson: is it not linker dependent(not compiler dependent)  ?

Comment: I don't know.  it could be either OS or compiler dependent.  A PE file has an entry point that is executed when the module is loaded (or maybe linked).  It would be possible to implement global initialization through that, but I don't know for certain that it is implemented that way.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case your failing to understand I have code here to demonstrate.
SourceA.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"

extern bool DoFunctionB();

class MyClassA {
protected:
    bool bIsInitialized;
    bool bIsBInitialized;
public:
    MyClassA () : bIsInitialized(true) {
        bIsBInitialized = DoFunctionB();
    }

    bool IsInitialized() {
        return bIsInitialized;
    }
};


static MyClassA MyClassGlobal;

bool DoFunctionA() {
    return MyClassGlobal.IsInitialized();
}
```

SourceB.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"

extern bool DoFunctionA();

class MyClassB {
protected:
    bool bIsInitialized;
    bool bIsAInitialized;
public:
    MyClassB () : bIsInitialized(true) {
        bIsAInitialized = DoFunctionA();
    }

    bool IsInitialized() {
        return bIsInitialized;
    }
};


static MyClassB MyClassGlobal;

bool DoFunctionB() {
    return MyClassGlobal.IsInitialized();
}
```

Main.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"

extern bool DoFunctionA();
extern bool DoFunctionB();

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    bool a = DoFunctionA();
    bool b = DoFunctionB();
    return 0;
}
```

Add these to a new windows console app.  Place breakpoints in the constructors, and in the DoFunctionX() code.  Hit F11 and step through it.  You will see that whichever global initializer gets called first will use the DoFunction in the other cpp file before the static object in that file gets initialized.

Regardless of what you think the standard may be.  This is what compilers do.  And its a hazard that you have to be concerned with.

And if you step up the stack 2 steps when your in the constructor you will see the list of pointers that I've already told you about.

Happy Coding.

Answer (score 0):

You are wrong to think that global constructors must be run before the object is used.  I've fixed many a bug based on this assumption and it simply is not true.  Not for gcc, and not for MSVC, abd certainly not for XCode.

You can specify an **attribute**((init_priority(X))) in gcc to force the order,

or #pragma init_seg({ compiler | lib | user | "section-name" [, func-name]} ) for msvc.

When working with XCode, the initialization code is run in the order that the object files are passed to the linker.

I dont think there is a standard, and if there is then very few people are following it.  Its up to the tools creator to decide how they want to keep track of whats getting initialized and when.

Comment: The standard merely states that all global objects in a translation unit will be initialized before anything in the translation unit is used (from external code).  I know the difficulties involved with dealing with global object initialization, and that is not what I am looking at.  What I am looking at is how the compilers or ABIs implement calling constructors and destructors of global objects.

Comment: Global objects get initialized before main.  Which standard are you quoting?  There is not a compiler one that supports that argument.  Create 2 translation units.  In the headers add 2 class declarations, and export a static global of that class, 1 per unit.  In the .cpp file add constructor code that references the other units global static object, and call a method on it.  Compile, run, and see which one gets used before it is initialized.

Comment: And while your at it, but a break point in the constructor, walk up the stack, and see how they get initialized.  Each Translation unit has a list, the lists get concatenated together, and the list gets initialized.  The initialization priority gives you some control over where things appear in the list.

Comment: Dan: 3.6.2/4 in ISO/IEC 14882:2011 "It is implementation-deﬁned whether the dynamic initialization of a non-local variable with static storage duration is done before the ﬁrst statement of main. If the initialization is deferred to some point in time after the ﬁrst statement of main, it shall occur before the ﬁrst odr-use (3.2) of any function or variable deﬁned in the same translation unit as the variable to be initialized."

Comment: If main is not in that unit then what is it you think is found there that is doing anything? Nothing that is not called from outside of that unit, for sure.  This is not different from what I said, what this says is if you don't initialize before main its ok as long as you do before something from main uses it.  There is nothing but main doing anything that's not global initialization. There is nothing getting used outside of initialization that does not stem from main.